# JavaScript: Usando Regex para formatar o CPF enquanto é digitado

Tags: javascript, regex

Estou montando funções JavaScript para aplicar máscaras enquanto o usuário digita. Mas estou na duvida se o Regex não reduziria mais o código.

```
function getFormatedCPF(unformatedValue) {
    const onlyDigits = unformatedValue.toString().replace(/[^\d]/g, "").substring(0, 11);

    if (onlyDigits.length > 9) return onlyDigits.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1.$2.$3-");
    if (onlyDigits.length > 6) return onlyDigits.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})/, "$1.$2.");
    if (onlyDigits.length > 3) return onlyDigits.replace(/(\d{3})/, "$1.");

    return onlyDigits;
}
```

O Motivo pelo qual coloquei estes `if`s é porque a máscara só estava sendo aplicada quando o `cpf` era digitado por inteiro. Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer com que a leitura seja "condicional" ou opcional.

Comment: Como essa funcao `getFormatedCPF` é chamada? Coloque, se possível, o códiog minimo para que seja possível testar e entender melhor o seu caso. Inclua o HTML se estiver usando ele.

Comment: Essa função será chamada tanto quando a tela for carregada e precisa aplicar a mascara quanto quando o um campo do tipo input que seja para o CPF receber um evento de keypress. Basta copiar ela para o console e colocar o cpf como uma string dentro do parametro

Comment: Talvez uns [ajustes](https://jsfiddle.net/vrz416mo/) já resolveria seu problema.

Comment: Na pergunta indicada acima tem uma regex que insere o ponto a cada 3 posições corretamente, independente da quantidade de dígitos. Basta adaptar para o seu caso (por exemplo, pegar somente os 9 primeiros, colocar os pontos, e depois concatenar com os dígitos verificadores, caso tenham sido digitados).

Comment: Eu espero que sim... Se possivel eu gostaria de remover esses IFs e usar apenas a lógica do regex para obter o mesmo resultado :/ ... Se fizesse com um loop talvez o problema ja estivesse resolvido, mas eu realmente queria entender se tem um jeito melhor de fazer esse código